# Migrating Log4j 1x(1.17.2) to 2x(2.17.1) Facing issues, logs are not rolling

Tags: java, websphere, log4j2

```
    I am trying to migrate to Log4J 2.x:
    
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.1'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.1'
    
    Do I need to use `log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1` dependency too?
    
    I changed all my `logger` to `logManager`. Here is my config:
    
        String config = url.toString();
        Configurator.initialize(null, config);
        LOGGER.info("Log4j initialized from " + url );
    
    Could you please help me to fix this issue, any suggestions what I suppose to do??
    please help me...
   

log4j2.xml File:::
    
    
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="DEBUG">
        <Appenders>
            <Console   name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                 <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%p] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
                <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="DEBUG"/>
            </Console>
    
            <RollingFile name="REPTOR_FILE"
                fileName="${cpp.rplr.log.loc}AppCmn.log"
                filePattern="${cpp.rplr.log.loc}AppCmn.log.%i.gz">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%p] %c{1} - %m%n" />
                <Policies>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
                <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="DEBUG"/>
            </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
        <Logger name ="com.delta" value="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="REPTOR_FILE" />
        </Logger>
            <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            </Root>
        <!--    <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="REPTOR_FILE" />
            </Root>  --> 
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
    
    Error logs::
```

### 2022-03-07 15:20:02,632 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=1b28cdfa, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1c72da34] 2022-03-07 15:20:02,635 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=1b28cdfa, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1c72da34]... 2022-03-07 15:20:02,643 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager ${css.rplr.log.loc}CssCrewRplrCmn.log 2022-03-07 15:20:02,644 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager ${css.rplr.log.loc}CssCrewRplrCmn.log 2022-03-07 15:20:02,645 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG OutputStream closed 2022-03-07 15:20:02,646 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager shutdown completed with status true 2022-03-07 15:20:02,646 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down RollingFileManager ${css.rplr.log.loc}CssCrewRplrCmn.log, all resources released: true 2022-03-07 15:20:02,647 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Appender REPTOR_FILE stopped with status true 2022-03-07 15:20:02,648 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false 2022-03-07 15:20:02,648 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG OutputStream closed 2022-03-07 15:20:02,648 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false, all resources released: true 2022-03-07 15:20:02,649 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Appender CONSOLE stopped with status true 2022-03-07 15:20:02,651 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped 2022-03-07 10:19:54,485 main ERROR Logger contains an invalid element or attribute "value" it is not logging anything instead of it is shutting down the log4j2 appenders

```
 Thanks in advance
```

Comment: could you please post the value of the actual config? what is located at `url`? :)

Comment: config: test/com/delta/css/rplr/cmn/resources/Log4jCnfg.xml
could you please review my log4j2.xml too, correct me if it is wrong

Comment: <Loggers name="java.sql"
       level="INFO" >
  <appender-ref ref="REPTOR_FILE" />
 </Loggers>
 <Loggers name ="org.springframework"
          level="DEBUG">
 </Loggers>
 <Loggers name ="org.mybatis">
    <level value="INFO"/>
 </Loggers>
 <Loggers name ="com.delta">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
 </Loggers>
 <Loggers>
     <Root level="DEBUG">
  <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
  </Root>
 <!--   <Root level="DEBUG">
  <AppenderRef ref="REPTOR_FILE" />
  </Root> -->
 </Loggers> this is how my root loggers are

Comment: ERROR Loggers contains invalid attributes "level", "name"
ERROR loggers Loggers has no parameter that matches element appender-ref
DEBUG createLoggers(={})
DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
 ERROR Loggers contains invalid attributes "level", "name
 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3eb91815]
 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager ${cpp.rplr.log.loc}CssCrewRplrCmn.log
 DEBUG OutputStream closed
  DEBUG All asynchronous threads have terminated

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.